# Mathematically: are magnetic field lines (almost) closed loops?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, differential-geometry, mathematical-physics

### Question:

Let $X:[0, 1] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^3$ be a smooth curve, and $\mathbf{B}$ be the vector field in $\mathbb{R}^3$ defined as
$$ \mathbf{B}(y) = \int_{\mathbb{R}^3} \frac{y-X(t)}{\|y-X(t)\|^3} \times X'(t) \ dt.$$
Considering the flow of $\mathbf{B}$, here are some possibilities for its orbits:

1. singleton (where $\mathbf{B} = 0$)
2. closed loop (periodic orbit)
3. Not closed, but limits (including point at infinity) as $t \rightarrow \infty$ and $t \rightarrow -\infty$ both exist.

Can there exist other possibilites? (e.g. orbit which asymptotically approaches to a closed loop)

### Details:

By Biot-Savart law, $\mathbf{B}$ is the magnetic field generated by current through the curve $X$ (I must have missed some constants), and the flow of $\mathbf{B}$ is called 'magnetic field lines.'
I could found affirmative answers like 'Yes, because there is no magnetic monopole', but I desire to find mathematical proof/counterexample.

Comment: I think it’s a very good question!

Comment: is it magnetic dipole or monopole?, magnetic dipole do exist (they are the magnetic field you get from a simple wire loop, with a constant flow of current). magnetic monopoles tend to be the ones people bring up when talking about closed loops with magnetic fields

Comment: @Nyra Thanks for the comment. I made a mistake, and now I corrected my question.

Comment: See the answers to [Must magnetic field lines close upon themselves or go to infinity?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/311127/64473)

Comment: @LouisB Thank you, the thread answers my question. By the way, the answer is suprising to me.

Comment: Small correction: The integral shouldn't be over $\mathbb{R}^3$ but over $[0,1].$